# Getting custom attributes from laravel many to many

Tags: php, laravel-5, pivot-table, eloquent

So i'm currently working on a module on my laravel web app where users can create multiple projects which can then have multiple contributors who will have to be accepted by the owners. I've successfully gotten the owner user part working by using this in the Project model

```
public function owner()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('younite\User', 'owner_id');
}
```

Now my issues is mapping user contributors to different projects as well as getting their acceptance status. I thought of using MANYTOMANY pivot tables as said here https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many but i'm having trouble figuring out how to create and **acessing** a custom 'status' column in the project_user table.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: share your all relevent Model relations and some more details, so we can provide you help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hehe sorry about this, but i figured it out i just had to create an extra 'status' column from my migration file for the pivot_table and i used this code in the project model file to get the status of a user

```
public function users() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('younite\User')->withPivot('status')->withTimestamps();
}
```